# Why can't I use the same Image twice?

Tags: javafx, imageview, gridpane

I have been trying to learn more on using JavaFX and in this program I am trying to display a 3 by 3 game of tic tac toe that has already been played. I have created my ImageViews and set the images I want to use but once I started plugging them into columns and rows I noticed I cannot use the same one twice. I have an image for an empty space, an X, and an O. Once I use one more than once I get an "Exception while running application". Might be a rookie mistake, but an explanation would be greatly appreciated.

```
package Fresh;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Fresh extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
       //Create a pane and set its properties
        GridPane pane = new GridPane();
        pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        pane.setPadding(new Insets(11.5, 12.5, 13.5, 14.5));
        pane.setHgap(5.5);
        pane.setVgap(5.5);

        //imv0 = X image
        final ImageView imv0 = new ImageView();
        final Image image0 = new Image(Fresh.class.getResourceAsStream("images/x.gif"));
        imv0.setImage(image0);

        //imv1 = O image
        final ImageView imv1 = new ImageView();
        final Image image1 = new Image(Fresh.class.getResourceAsStream("images/o.gif"));
        imv1.setImage(image1);

        //imv2 = empty image
        final ImageView imv2 = new ImageView();
        final Image image2 = new Image(Fresh.class.getResourceAsStream("images/empty.gif"));
        imv2.setImage(image2);

        //Place nodes in the pane
        pane.add((imv0),0,0);
        pane.add((imv1), 1, 0);

//Once I try to use imv0 again "I get an exception while running". 
        pane.add((imv0),0,1);

        //Create a scene and place it in the stage
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        primaryStage.setTitle("ShowGridPane");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the same `Image` as many times as you like; however, you can only place a given `ImageView` in one place in the scene graph. From the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html):

> A node may occur at most once anywhere in the scene graph.

To see why this must be true, what would you expect

```
GridPane.getColumnIndex(imv0)
```

to return, given the code you have?

So you can do:

```
final Image image0 = new Image(Fresh.class.getResourceAsStream("images/x.gif"));
ImageView imv00 = new ImageView(image0);
ImageView imv01 = new ImageView(image0);

pane.add(imv00, 0, 0);
pane.add(imv01, 0, 1);

// etc
```

The overhead here is not too bad; you use the same image data for each `ImageView`.

Comment: Shouldn't `ImageView imv01 = new ImageView(image1);` also use `image0` instead of `image1` ?